# Bash: ls says file not found

Tags: bash

I tried the following command

```
for i in `ls`; do ls $i; done
```

and got the following output:

```
ls: a.out: No such file or directory
ls: c: No such file or directory
ls: contest: No such file or directory
ls: cpp: No such file or directory
ls: java: No such file or directory
ls: : No such file or directory
```

It is confusing since the list of files was also obtained using `ls`. When I tried to do an `od` on `echo`, i see the following:

```
0000000 033 133 060 155 033 133 060 061 073 063 062 155 141 056 157 165 
        033   [   0   m 033   [   0   1   ;   3   2   m   a   .   o   u   
0000020 164 033 133 060 155 012 
          t 033   [   0   m  \n  
0000026
0000000 033 133 060 061 073 063 064 155 143 033 133 060 155 012 
        033   [   0   1   ;   3   4   m   c 033   [   0   m  \n  
0000016
0000000 033 133 060 061 073 063 064 155 143 157 156 164 145 163 164 033 
        033   [   0   1   ;   3   4   m   c   o   n   t   e   s   t 033 
0000020 133 060 155 012 
          [   0   m  \n  
0000024
0000000 033 133 060 061 073 063 064 155 143 160 160 033 133 060 155 012 
        033   [   0   1   ;   3   4   m   c   p   p 033   [   0   m  \n  
0000020
0000000 033 133 060 155 146 151 154 145 056 164 170 164 033 133 060 155 
        033   [   0   m   f   i   l   e   .   t   x   t 033   [   0   m   
0000020 012 
         \n  
0000021
0000000 033 133 060 061 073 063 064 155 152 141 166 141 033 133 060 155 
        033   [   0   1   ;   3   4   m   j   a   v   a 033   [   0   m   
0000020 012 
         \n  
0000021
0000000 033 133 155 012 
        033   [   m  \n  
0000004
```

What does these "033 [ 0 m" characters stand for? How do I avoid them? Are they the cause of this problem?

Please help.

Thanks,
Karthick S.

Comment: The "033 [ 0 m" characters are escape codes for colouring terminal output. Try using this instead: for file in $(unset LS_COLORS \ls); do ls "$file"; done

Comment: Thanks a lot pgl. Can you please make it an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "033 [ 0 m" characters are escape codes for colouring terminal output. Try using this instead:

```
for file in $(unset LS_COLORS \ls);
do
     ls "$file";
done
```

Comment: I would expect ls to not use colors when not writing to tty.

Comment: @johannes `ls --color=auto` checks this. The default is `always` (--color without argument) and can also be `never`.

Comment: On my system `man ls` says: "Using color to distinguish file types is disabled both by default,..."

Comment: This is may be an answer but the method is flawed see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) and use @mouviciel solution

Comment: @potong you're correct, using * is the way to go, but it wouldn't've explained why things weren't working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `` `ls` `` or `$(ls)`. You can use `*` instead. This way you avoid fancy colored outputs while leaving your code both portable, readable and compact.

Answer (score 3):

This is #1 in [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
NEVER use `ls` as input for another command...

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
for file in $(ls -1 -Q --quoting-style=shell --color=never);
do
    ls "$file";
done
```